# How do you "climb" or "move around" the Tower?

Tags: tower-of-god

In the manga and anime series, there isn't really much that shows the climbing of the tower, since in the first episode, Bam (and after him, Rachael) are both teleported onto the second floor by Haedon, while Yuri and Evan take some sort of "stair" that look like interdimensional travel. What's going on?

Is a floor some sort of separate pocket universe world?

There's also mention of an "inner", "outer" and "middle" tower, which do not have any sort of visible structure (we jump between scenes).